# JIRA - 指定した期間内に変更されたチケットをJQLで抽出したい

Tags: sql

指定した期間内で変更があったJIRAチケットを抽出するJQLを書きたいのですが、
可能なのでしょうか。

> priority CHANGED BEFORE "2015/05/11" AFTER "2015/05/22"

これではうまく抽出できませんでした。

> updated > "2015/05/11" AND updated <= "2015/05/22"

この方法だと、最新の変更日のみが対象となってしまうため、要件を満たしませんでした。

Comment: うまく抽出できなかったというのは、 `priority` 以外の変更も対象にしたいということでしょうか？

Comment: はい、updated timeの更新がかかるような、JIRAチケットに与えられたあらゆる変更を対象としたいです。